# how to hit controller action method from within javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is the url which i am trying to hit from within .js file which contains knockout related function:

```
 self.followAction = $.resolvePath("/People/Follow?uid=" + data.UserId);
```

here People is the controller and Follow is the action method, on button click, i want to send userId along so i have written this.

To resolve relative path from within javascript, i have written this function

```
// Fix for resolving relative paths from within js scripts
 $.resolvePath = function(url)
 {
  var path = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
  if (path != '/') return path + url;
  return url;
  };
```

But, on button click, i am getting this error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
and url is:

```
 localhost:44305/People/@Request.ApplicationPath/People/Follow?uid=8
```

please tell me what should i try now. thnks in advance!

Comment: Razor code is not interpreted within JS files, hence the `@Request.ApplicationPath` is read as a literal string. You need to put that code somewhere where it will be executed so that your JS can read it; as a `data-*` attribute on an element in your View, for example.

Comment: okk thnk u got it @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Comment: My problem is still not solved please someone help me @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 3):

Razor code is not interpreted within JS files, hence the `@Request.ApplicationPath` is read as a literal string. You need to put that code somewhere where it will be executed so that your JS can read it; perhaps as a `data-*` attribute on an element in your View, something like this:

```html
<!-- in a layout view... -->
<body data-app-path="@Request.ApplicationPath">
```

```js
$.resolvePath = function(url) {
    var path = $('body').data('app-path');
    if (path != '/') 
        return path + url;
    return url;
};
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have tried putting that code in a partial view and call that partial view directly on view page but still it is saying $.resolvepath is not a function and in your answer what is data-app-path and where to put code in layout i think it should be in head section @Rory McCrossan

Comment: It is not working i dont know why what should be done

Comment: You would probably be best to start a new question about it, including the actual HTML which is output and the value of `@Request.ApplicationPath`